# Programmatically creating an object in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, factory

Is there a way in Spring to get an object programmatically as if it was injected by the xml file.

Here is what i mean

I have this class called securityDelegate. It's instances are always created by spring

```
<bean id="securityDelegate" class="securityBusinessDelegate" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="securityServiceEJB" ref="securityServiceEJB"/>
    <property name="securityService" ref="securityService"/>
  </bean>
```

I need to use an instance of this class in a SessionListener, and as I understand, since this is at a servlet level, I can't inject an instance of securityDelegate into my `HttpSessionListener` implementation.

What I would like to do is to retrieve an instance through java code, inside my implementation, to do something like this

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

 //other methods
 @Override
 public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    //get an instance of securityBusinessDelegate here

    securityBusinessDelegate.doSomething();
 }
}
```

I seem to recall this was possible last time I used spring (3+ years ago), but I could be confused. Maybe setting up a factory?

Comment: Ok, I'm aware its <b>wrong</b> to answer my own question, so i'll put this here in case anyone bumps into this problem: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-how-to-do-dependency-injection-in-your-session-listener/

Comment: I thought you get a badge for that "Self Learner"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(se.getServletContext.());
ctx.getBean("securityDelegate");
```

Comment: You'll need to cast the thing you get back to the class you want, "getBean" returns Object.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;    
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

 @Override
 public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    ServletContext servletCtx = se.getSession().getServletContext();
    ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletCtx);
    YourClass securityBusinessDelegate = ctx.getBean(YourClass.class);

    securityBusinessDelegate.doSomething();
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yep, use a factory. Just a much more complicated one. DI/IoC Geniuses.